# Restrict access to list programmatically

Tags: client-object-model

I am updating a list MasterData programmatically using data which a user has entered in a small custom application. Application uses credentials entered by the user to login to Sharepoint, through Client COM.

If the user tries to open the list directly from their browser -

```
   http://myURL/List_name
```

they are able to view it.

I would like to restrict this so that they cannot view the list at all from their browser. But application should still be able to use their login details to enter the data.
How can this be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish it you can break the permissions on the list so users can't access it and since  there is no way to elevate the privileges using the client object model because it would be a severe security breach you can just create your own custom web service\WCF service and update the list on server side using [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx). Here's a nice [tutorial](http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/sharepoint-2010-create-custom-wcf.html)  on how to create a custom WCF service.

Comment: Thanks for the link Alex. But I'm not sure if I would have permissions to create a service on the server. I will try and update back here. Is there any other way?